# How to keep shared data after page refresh in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and looking for a solution for maintaining shared data on Page Refresh.

I have 2 components i.e. Coolers and Formulation. Cooler component shares selected cooler information to Formulation component. I have used shared service here to pass data between 2 components. After navigation data is present for Formulation component. After page refresh, data is lost. How to maintain data on/after page refresh.

Component1 (Cooler):

```
createQuotation(){
    this.selectedCoolers = [];
    for(let i=0; i< this.coolers.length; i++)
    {
      if(this.coolers[i].check)
      {
        this.selectedCoolers.push(this.coolers[i]);
      }
    }
    this.coolerservice.updateSelectedCoolers(this.selectedCoolers);
  }
```

Shared Service (CoolerService)

```
updateSelectedCoolers(coolers : Cooler[]){
        console.log("From updateSelectedCoolers");
        console.log(coolers);
        this._selectedCoolersSource.next(coolers);
    }
```

Components2 (Formulation):

```
selectedCoolers : Cooler[];
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient, private coolerservice: CoolerService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.coolerservice.selectedCoolers$.subscribe(
      coolers => {
        console.log("In ngOnInit");
        console.log(coolers);
        this.selectedCoolers = coolers;
        console.log(this.selectedCoolers); //Line1
      }
    );
    console.log("After Navigation");
    console.log(this.selectedCoolers); //Line2
  }
```

selectedCoolers have more than 50.
I want to keep data in this.selectedCoolers after page refresh.
Also 'console.log(this.selectedCoolers); //Line2' is showing undefined.

Comment: You can keep your data either in session storage or local storage as soon as you get the data.

Comment: selectedCoolers have count more than 50. Is it good way to store all that data in local/session storage? Thanks for quick reply. :)

Comment: You can store maximum of 10MB  of data in local storage and 50 data points is a very small, i don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: Stored data in session storage and it worked. 

But what is the use of Service here? sessionStorage.setItem can be done from Component1 and sessionStorage.getItem from Component2.

Comment: Added my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your data either in **session storage** or **local storage** as soon as you get the data.

You can store maximum of **10MB** of data in local storage and 50 data points is a very small, i don't think it will be an issue.

You can definitely do that from component itself but It is **recommended to write code in service** if it has nothing to do with component. Right now you are storing data in local storage so use service. **It will keep your code less messy and scalable.**

Let say you want to perform some manipulations before storing them to local storage in future,  you can easily do that in service class. Isolation always helps as your application grow.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data as route param. After reloading you can get it from the url.

We can append data in your url params by using `navigate` and `navigateByUrl` in Router. And we can get data in the component by using ActivatedRoute Example:

```
this._ActivatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        if(params){
          // params is your data from last component
        }
});
```

There is no need of service for passing these type of data from one component to another.

You can set data in url param by

```
this._Router.navigate([url],{queryParams:$objectvariable});
```